# Ratio Calculation in SQL based on different date fields

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to calculate the number of contacts made/number of orders placed per day
This is how my sample looks like:

```
orderID orderdate   ContactID   contact date
    1   11-May        A          12-May
    2   12-May        B          12-May
    3   12-May        NULL       NULL
    4   12-May        C          13-May
    5   13-May        D          14-May
```

EX: My ratio 12thMay would be 2/3(1,2,3 and A,B)
Need to do it without any joins.
Can you please help me with a SQL or Hive Query for this

Comment: Per calendar week? To know the calendar week, the dates need a year part!

Comment: Per day. Sorry. Edited the question

Comment: Are your date fields in date format? They look like chars

Comment: They are in the date format in original db. this sample is manually typed. So they look as chars

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the ratio you're looking for:

```
Select isnull(orderdate, contactdate), concat(cast(isnull(contacts,0) as char),'/',cast(isnull(orders,0) as char)) as Ratio
from
(Select orderdate, count(orderdate) orders
from tbl
where orderdate is not null
Group by orderdate) o
left join
(Select contactdate, count(contactdate) contacts
from tbl
where contactdate is not null
Group by contactdate) c on o.orderdate = c.contactdate
UNION
Select isnull(orderdate, contactdate), cast(isnull(contacts,0) as varchar) + '/' + cast(isnull(orders,0) as varchar)
from
(Select orderdate, count(orderdate) orders
from @foobar
where orderdate is not null
Group by orderdate) o
right join
(Select contactdate, count(contactdate) contacts
from @foobar
where contactdate is not null
Group by contactdate) c on o.orderdate = c.contactdate
```

I've added a Union to this in order to replicate a Full Outer Join in case there is a date in contact date that is not in order date

Comment: Thanks Christian. But I was looking for a way to do it without joins. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to do it correctly without a join due to the nature of your table. Why don't you want to use joins?

Answer (score 0):

U need to count elements for each colum grouped by day, and then make the division.

Here u are the Query with two columns as result. The decimal division, and his string representation:

```
select A.orderdate, 
CONVERT(decimal(4,2),numOrders)/CONVERT(decimal(4,2),numContacts) as DecimalRate, 
CONVERT(varchar(max),numOrders) + '/' + CONVERT(varchar(max),numContacts) textualRate

from 
(
select orderdate, count(*) as numOrders from AtestTable
group by orderdate ) A
left join
(
select contactdate, count(*) as numContacts from AtestTable
group by contactdate
) B
on A.orderDate = B.contactDate
```

Comment: Thanks Tima. But I was looking for a way to do it without joins. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Without joins?   Wow....   
can u explan why please?
Can we make it with an stored procedure?

Comment: I'm using this in an external reporting tool that doesn't allow me to join.

Comment: Can u create a view with the SQL   and then call the view through your external tool?

Answer (score 0):

I have a quick and dirty solution that seems to be getting the results you are looking for.

```
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE (
    OrderId int,
    OrderDate date,
    ContactID varchar(5),
    ContactDate date
)

INSERT INTO @TestTable
VALUES
    (1,'5/11/2015','A','5/12/2015'),
    (2,'5/12/2015','B','5/12/2015'),
    (3,'5/12/2015',NULL,NULL),
    (4,'5/12/2015','C','5/13/2015'),
    (5,'5/13/2015','D','5/14/2015')

DECLARE @Dates TABLE (
    TheDate DATE
)

INSERT INTO @Dates
SELECT DISTINCT OrderDate FROM @TestTable
INSERT INTO @Dates
SELECT DISTINCT ContactDate FROM @TestTable WHERE ContactDate NOT IN (SELECT * FROM @Dates)


SELECT
    D.TheDate,
    --Order Ratio
    CAST((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @TestTable WHERE OrderDate = TheDate) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/' + CAST((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @TestTable) AS VARCHAR(2)) AS 'OrderRatio',
    CAST((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @TestTable WHERE OrderDate = TheDate) AS DECIMAL)/CAST((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @TestTable) AS DECIMAL) AS 'OrderDecimal',
    --Contact Ratio
    CAST((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @TestTable WHERE ContactDate = TheDate) AS VARCHAR(3)) + '/' + CAST((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @TestTable) AS VARCHAR(3)) AS 'ContactRatio',
    CAST((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @TestTable WHERE ContactDate = TheDate) AS DECIMAL)/CAST((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @TestTable) AS DECIMAL) AS 'ContactDecimal'
FROM
    @Dates D
```

The result set looks like:

```
TheDate         OrderRatio     OrderDecimal             ContactRatio    ContactDecimal
2015-05-11      1/5            0.2000000000000000000    0/5             0.0000000000000000000
2015-05-12      3/5            0.6000000000000000000    2/5             0.4000000000000000000
2015-05-13      1/5            0.2000000000000000000    1/5             0.2000000000000000000
2015-05-14      0/5            0.0000000000000000000    1/5             0.2000000000000000000
```